# Fast removal of low frequency words in Python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

In the code below, lowFrequencyWords is a list with the low frequency words and doc is a list of tokens.

```
doc=[w for w in doc if not w in lowFrequencyWords]
```

The problem is that this piece of code lasts forever.

I am note sure, but I believe that the problem is that the operation of removal of an intermediate element from a list costs O(n), where n is the size of the list. Since the number of lowFrequencyWords is giant, python has to repeat that many times. I looked for linked lists, but I believe that they are not available in Python.

Comment: So doc of `['a', 'a', 'b']` where `w` just has `b` would result in `['a', 'a']` ?

Comment: make `lowFrequencyWords` a `frozenset(lowFrequencyWords)` to begin with ...

Comment: also using `doc[:] = [w for w in doc if w not in frozenset_of_lowFreq]` might help - not sure - someone told me thats some kind of inplace replacing which might be faster. dont ask me, just heard it...

Comment: @JonClements yes!

Comment: How big is `doc` @Daniel? Either that (take its difference and then rebuild it) or `lowFrequencyWords` should be a set for O(1) lookup...

Comment: @PatrickArtner the solution with a frozenset (unless I did something wrong - I am still testing) seems realy fast! Why?

Comment: because you mostly look into the list with O(n) lookup and never find your words (they are low freq). So you essentially iterate all of lowFreqWords _all the time_. sets have constant lookups - thats fast compared. frozensets are just the immutable cousins of sets.

Comment: @PatrickArtner The `doc[:] = ` there is nothing to do with speed... Just mutability... `a = [1, 2, 3]; b = a`... then do `a = [4, 5, 6]`... you just rebind the name `a` to a new list and `b` is still referring to the original.... if you do `a[:] = [4, 5, 6]` then you're mutating the underlying list that `a` and `b` refer to so `b` will also be referring to the updated list.

Comment: @JonClements thanks for explaining - it was some kind of "obscure" tip I got 15 months back when starting on pyhton or so and never understood correctly it seems. Ok, banned from the "optimize speed" category of list comps :)

Comment: @Daniel out of curiosity is `lowFrequencyWords` based on what's in `doc` itself or is it based on something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from comments: @Patrick Artner
make lowFrequencyWords a frozenset(lowFrequencyWords) to begin with